# Relationship between residual term and sum of deviations of dependent variable

Tags: regression, economics

So I wanted to know how we get from the first to the second step in this equation. Note that the lower case y denotes deviations from the mean i.e. (Yi-Ybar). I know that summation(Ybar*Ui(hat)) would be zero since Ybar goes out of the summation sign and summation of Ui is 0. But why would Summation(Yi*Ui(hat)) be zero.

[Screenshot of the equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHfL8.png)

(Apologies I'm still learning how to write mathematical notation in the in-built code format that the text editor includes.)

Comment: What's $\hat{y}$ supposed to be? It's pretty standard to denote the observed outcome $y_i$, the predicted outcome following a regression as $\hat{y}_i$, and the observed deviation $\hat{u}_i = y_i - \hat{y}_i$, are you sure that isn't what you were referring to?